# Replicating table setup from ORC to Parquet

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have the following table definition with ORC that I would like to replicate to Parquet (there are more fields I am not showing):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_a`(
  `some_id` int,
  `sha_sum` string,
  `parent_sha_sum` string,
  `md5_sum` string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `server_date` date
)
CLUSTERED BY (
  sha_sum
)
SORTED BY (
  sha_sum, parent_sha_sum, md5_sum
)
INTO 256 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://cluster/user/myuser/test_a'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'orc.compress'='ZLIB',
  'orc.create.index'='true',
  'orc.stripe.size'='130023424',
  'orc.row.index.stride'='64000',
  'orc.create.index'='true';
```

I was wondering how can I replicate this to Parquet. I would like to use ZLIB or something like that for compression, I would like to have indexes and potentially tune some of the TBLPROPERTIES for Parquet.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_b`(
  `some_id` int,
  `sha_sum` string,
  `parent_sha_sum` string,
  `md5_sum` string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `server_date` date
)
CLUSTERED BY (
  sha_sum
)
SORTED BY (
  sha_sum, parent_sha_sum, md5_sum
)
INTO 256 BUCKETS
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'hdfs://cluster/user/myuser/test_b'
TBLPROPERTIES (
 'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true'
)
```

Is there a list of all of the options available for Parquet through TBLPROPERTIES?

Comment: Not sure there is _any_ option for Parquet... compression, for instance, is set on a case-by-case basis cf. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html#parquet_hive

Comment: And "indexes" does not sound like a Parquet feature.